# Windows shell nested for loops

Tags: shell, for-loop, windows-shell

I wanted to run a program several times with two increasing input parameters. For this purpose I had to write a small shell script containing two nested for loops. For some reason, that I didn't understood the script stops its execution before printing all values.

```
for /l %%r in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) do (
    for /l %%c in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) do (
        rem Run my program here!
        echo %%r %%c 
    )
)
```

The output is

```
1 1
1 3
3 1
3 3
```

I'm really lost, as I'm no expert in windows shell programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the /l flag, which has the following properties:

```
for /l %%X in (start, step, end) do command
```

So in your case:

```
Start: 1
Step : 2
End  : 3
```

So thats why you get:

```
(1, 1), (1,3), (3,1), (3,3)
```

If you remove the /l you should get the results as expected.

```
echo off
for  %%r in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) do (
    for  %%c in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) do (
        echo %%r %%c 
    )
)
```

Which returns (1,1) to (10,10).

You can find more information [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Just copied the code above. I have to mention that I only use shell programming, if I have to. I'll try your code next Monday.